# Why can't I observe NSApplicationXYZNotification with addObserverForName?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to make an Objective-C iOS library work for macOS applications. Removing UIKit-based notifications is the only real task here. When trying to replace—for example—`UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` with `NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification`, I run into the odd error of the latter variable being called an undeclared identifier.

```
[self.observers addObject: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification* note) {
    // stop operations
}]];
```

The same error does not arise when I use the alternate method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:[???] selector:[some selector] name:NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification object:nil];
```

The problem with this method though is that I have to have an observer beforehand—like `self`—as opposed to receiving one that I can add to the `self.observers` array.

I've read a smattering of docs, questions, and guides—including the [NSApplication doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication?language=objc) and the [NSHipster guide](https://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/)—but I can't seem to figure out my misunderstanding, though I believe it is something fundamental about NSNotificationCenter and how it works.

Comment: I suppose a workaround might be to implement the `addObserver:selector:name:object:` method with observer as `self`, and rework the rest of the class to handle cleanup on its own, i.e. without the `observers` array. But this doesn't answer the underlying question.

Comment: The first code snippet is missing a `]` and doesn't generate a undeclared identifier error. Have you tried unnesting the statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly solution, though aided by @Willeke's comment that they weren't seeing an error with the same code snippet—the library needed Cocoa.h in place of the iOS imports.

Comment: It's still odd to me why `addObserver` was fine without Cocoa.h, but whatever.